# React/Node deployment on Netlify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern, netlify

I recently deployed an app to `heroku`. But I want to know how to deploy this same app to `Netlify`.

I created a script that works fine in Heroku :

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix 
client && npm run build --prefix client".
```

I added the same global variables as I did in `Heroku` and I also run the same script but I get this error:

```
2:34:44 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit 
code: 127
2:34:44 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
2:34:44 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned 
non-zero exit code: 127
2:34:44 PM: Finished processing build request in 25.404662076s
```

client package.json

```
    {
   "name": "client",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
   "axios": "^0.18.0",
   "classnames": "^2.2.5",
   "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
   "moment": "^2.22.0",
   "react": "^16.3.1",
   "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
   "react-moment": "^0.7.0",
   "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
   "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
   "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
   "redux": "^3.7.2",
   "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
      "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

server package.json

```
{
  "name": "devconnector",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Social network for developers",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
      "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
      "start": "node server.js",
      "server": "nodemon server.js",
      "client": "npm start --prefix client",
      "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
      "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install -- 
       prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
      "author": "Brad Traversy",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
           "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
           "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
           "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
           "express": "^4.16.3",
           "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
           "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
           "mongoose": "^5.0.12",
           "netlify-cli": "^1.2.3",
           "passport": "^0.4.0",
           "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
           "validator": "^9.4.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
           "nodemon": "^1.17.3"
      }
 }
```

Comment: post ur package json file

Comment: I have two. One for the Client and one for the Backend

Comment: That isn't enough information to debug.  The error is caused by some line further up the deploy logs that you haven't included.  Either post your full deploy logs (or a link to them if they are public - you can change that setting in the build & deploy settings configuration), or contact the helpdesk with a link to the deploy logs to get better advice:  support@netlify.com

Comment: Netlify is for building and deploying static sites ... you're barking up the wrong tree trying to deploy a node server to it.

Comment: Hey would did you get it to deploy on heroku. My app is build successfully but when visiting the website it shows application error

Comment: @Vincent as others here said, Netlify is not capable of hosting a backend. [link](https://github.com/raulsanchez1024/mernstarter) check this repo out it will deploy your frontend and backend on Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Netlify isn't as straight forward as Heroku when trying to deploy a backend. Basic answer, you can't.

https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/
There is a way to make it work, see above link, but I don't know how to do it.